# How to get timezone representation in GMT format

Tags: java

Our timezones are stored in the database as follows (e.g. America/Los_Angeles). How do I get the equivalent GMT representation from the above (e.g. GMT -08:00)

Answer (score 5):

Offset from GMT in hours:

```
import java.util.TimeZone

double offset = TimeZone.getTimeZone("America/Los_Angeles")
    .getRawOffset()/(60*60*1000.0);
// returns 8.0
```

However, this returns the raw offset. The offset changes depending on the timezone and the date due to Daylight Time Savings. To get the offset for a particular date use:

```
import java.util.TimeZone
import java.util.Calendar

Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
double offset = TimeZone.getTimeZone("America/Los_Angeles")
    .getOffset(cal.getTimeInMillis())/(60*60*1000.0); 
// returns -7.0 for 22/sep/2010
```

Answer (score 2):

There's a huge difference between those two:

- "America/Los_Angeles" lets you determine the local time given *any* UTC time
- "GMT -08:00" only tells you the difference between local time and UTC at *one instant*. It doesn't tell you about when or whether DST is applied, or how much DST is applied

In other words, "GMT -08:00" is an offset, *not* a time zone. Now you can *get* the offset at any particular instant fairly easily - I would personally use [Joda Time](http://joda-time.sf.net) for that - and format it appropriately. But *don't* think that you've actually got a reasonable representation of a time zone.